# How to limit the number of Tomcat threads?

Tags: centos, tomcat7, threads

I have a tomcat 7 running on a low memory CentOS. Currently it has 2 connectors for ports 80 and 443. Important configuration options are:

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" executor="tomcatThreadPool"
                connectionTimeout="10000"
                keepAliveTimeout="60000"

<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" executor="tomcatThreadPool"
                SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
                connectionTimeout="10000"
                keepAliveTimeout="60000"
```

Both connectors is bound to an executor:

```
<Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
                maxThreads="100" minSpareThreads="3"
                maxIdleTime="120000" />
```

When tomcat is first started, it starts about 50 threads. After about 15-20 users connecting to web application, it is increased to about 60. (I count tomcat threads with command `ps -eLf | grep java |grep tomcat |wc -l`)

I have about 4 connections per minute, it is not more than 5 due to the nature of my application. Therefore I want tomcat to start minimum possible threads. Since I have configured minimum of 3 spare threads and keepalive as 2 minutes, it should not go over 20 or something. But I am wrong.

How can I limit the number of Tomcat threads to a minimum value like 20 or 30?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/executor.html) the number of minimum threads can be configured using the following parameter:

<kbd>`Attribute`</kbd>      <kbd>`Description`</kbd>                                                         
<kbd>`minSpareThreads`</kbd><kbd>`(int) The minimum number of threads always kept alive, default is 25`</kbd>

According to [this documentation](http://www.genericarticles.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=How_to_optimize_tomcat_performance_in_production) it could be implemented as follows:

```
<Connector port="8080" address="localhost"     
     minSpareThreads="20" />
```

`At server startup, the HTTP Connector will create a number of processing threads based on the value configured for the minSpareThreads attribute.`

Comment: I used an executor and defined minSpareThreads but it does work. Should I use just connector and define minsparethreads?  As answered here executor allows to share a thread pool by connectors http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626211/tomcat-thread-pool-commented-out-in-tomcat-conf-should-i-use-it

Comment: @jdiver did you restart Tomcat after changing the server.xml?

Comment: Of course; I keep restart tomcat once each 2 days because it consumes all memory.

Comment: Ok that is interesting. Do you use a tool like JVisualVM to investigate the threads? Which tools are you using? I assume that you are using certain tools as you provide information regarding the amount of threads in the question.

Comment: I just restarted now and there are 52 threads.  Actually I don't understand why it is starting about 50 threads each time.

Comment: I just use ps command :  ps -eLf | grep java |grep tomcat |wc -l and pstree

Comment: @jdiver What is the number of maxThreads? Could you change it to 10 and the min to e.g. 5?

Comment: maxThreads value is 100

Comment: @jdiver it should be decreased if the number of maxThreads will be changed to e.g. 10. Could you verify this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18665/discussion-between-jdiver-and-utrecht).